# Should audio buffer size be high or low?

Tags: java, audio, udp

In my code below i send microphone input from my client to server. My question is if we change value of `CHUNK_SIZE` how would that affect our audio at the receiving end of the server? And should the  variable `numBytesRead` be used as length of the buffer to be sent with a datagrampacket or should it be `data.length`? (data.length = 17640 & numBytesRead = 1024)

```
        int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024;
        byte[] data = new byte[microphone.getBufferSize() / 5];
        microphone.start();

        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
            int numBytesRead;

            while(true) {
                numBytesRead = microphone.read(data, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);
                // bytesRead += numBytesRead;
                // write the mic data to a stream for use later
                out.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
                
                DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(data, numBytesRead, address, 5555);
                socket.send(request);

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the example, the reads and writes are being constrained by `CHUNK_SIZE`, which puts an upper limit on `numBytesRead`. So, yes, changing that value could effect performance. You could raise it all the way to 17640 and still make use of the `data` array. But I don't understand why such a large array and only making partial use of it.

In general, the larger the buffer, the greater the latency. But there can also be a pickup in the reliability of the playback. When buffers are too low, the playback can be plagued by dropouts or other artifacts.

To confirm:
Is `microphone` a `TargetDataLine`?
Is `out` a `SourceDataLine`?
Is it your intention to send the microphone data to two different outputs? (One local, one via Datagram?)

Comment: Sir, the out is actually used for an ByteArrayOutputStream so you can ignore that part. But yes, microphone is a targetdataline. The intention in this particular case was to record audio, store it in an array and transmit it to an server where it gets played.

Comment: But i also have a question: if our latency increases does that in any way affect the network jitter or vice versa? And what kinda programs would you recommend to track network jitter? Is a program like wireshark capable of tracking this efficiently?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer about network jitter, or how a larger buffer might affect that.

Comment: Thats no problem sir. But when you say that if a buffers value is too low it could be plagued by dropouts? Do you mean that if a buffer size is on the low side then more packets are lost when trying to reach a destination?

Comment: The problem is not that the packets are lost, but that some won't arrive in time. If a packet is large, it takes more time for the recipient to play back that packet, and during this interval more packets can arrive. If the packet is very small, there is a danger that the recipient will finish playing it and be waiting for the next packet to arrive. If it isn't there, it will play silence (with possible clicks at the start and stop points). The Java code that produces packets is not a steady stream, but occurs with starts and stops, due to multi-task switching that is part of Java processing.

Comment: When a packet isn't arrived in time isn't that refered to as delay in latency?

Comment: Or are you rather referring to the variance of arrival rate? That would be called network jitter.

Comment: I was thinking more of something that occurs even with non-network situations. This article breaks down issues with audio processing. http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/p/pod/dod-idx?c=icmc;idno=bbp2372.2007.131 The network adds yet another source of variability.

Comment: Where does that link refer you to?

Comment: Sorry to not include that. The link is to a pdf posted by the University of Michigan. It is an article titled "Real Time Low Latency Audio Processing in Java" by N. Juillerat and co-authors. You might be able to find another link if you search on the author and title. It remains relevant in its discussion of the basic issues of audio processing. Transport over the internet adds another layer of complication on top of the baseline issues that they discuss.

Comment: I also have another question sir. Does AudioSystem.isLineSupported() check whether our microphone device works?

Comment: I believe the method only checks if the functionality is supported. You might check the API-> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#isLineSupported-javax.sound.sampled.Line.Info- Also the tutorial-> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html

Comment: Hmmmm thanks for that link. But i have a question about CPU usage when we stream audio from the client to the server. If a have 50 clients that all stream audio to the server then my CPU usage increases by 30% wich is considerably a lot ofcourse i could increase the network latency so the cpu workload decreases but it still gets very high after a certain amount of client. For a client with a buffer of 1024 bytes i get around 170 packets per one second. How would i be able to handle lets say a thousand clients if after only 50 clients the cpu workload increases by 30%?